# pcDuino 3B Wire library errors

Tags: i2c, library, wire-library

I recently purchased a pcDuino 3B and I am very pleased with the Board so far. I can use the preinstalled arduino IDE to program the board from the board and run programs.

However, when I came to use I2C, it generated a load of errors with the built-in libraries when I tried to compile. I don't know why it did this, it does it when trying to compile any program using I2C. Here is the error list (Yes, I am using an Adafruit display library that works fine with exactly the same sketch on my laptop):

```
In file included from /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/pcduino/cores/arduino/Stream.h:26:0,
                 from /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/pcduino/libraries/Wire/Wire.h:9,
                 from Stopwatch_new.ino:1:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/pcduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:47:23: error: ‘byte’ has not been declared
In file included from Stopwatch_new.ino:1:0:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/pcduino/libraries/Wire/Wire.h:41:23: error: ‘byte’ has not been declared
Stopwatch_new.ino:5:51: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Adafruit_RGBLCDShield’
/home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/AdafruitLCD/Adafruit_RGBLCDShield.h:68:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Adafruit_RGBLCDShield’:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/pcduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:47:17: note:  virtual int Print::write(int)
Stopwatch_new.ino:5:23: error: cannot declare variable ‘lcd’ to be of abstract type ‘Adafruit_RGBLCDShield’
/home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/AdafruitLCD/Adafruit_RGBLCDShield.h:68:7: note:   since type ‘Adafruit_RGBLCDShield’ has pure virtual functions
Stopwatch_new.ino: In function ‘void updateScreen()’:
Stopwatch_new.ino:125:27: error: call of overloaded ‘String(float&, int)’ is ambiguous
Stopwatch_new.ino:125:27: note: candidates are:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/pcduino/cores/arduino/WString.h:44:14: note: String::String(unsigned int, unsigned char)
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/pcduino/cores/arduino/WString.h:43:14: note: String::String(int, unsigned char)
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/pcduino/cores/arduino/WString.h:42:14: note: String::String(unsigned char, unsigned char)
```

It seems that no one else is having this issue.

Just to clarify, the issue is not with my code or the library, it compiles fine on my other computer running WINDOWS but same Arduino version (1.5.3), same sketch code and same library code.

Help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the libraries for compiling were incomplete. Having copied the libraries for the official IDE, it worked fine.